# Java - Using an Address object to update two complex fields(Office address & Home Address) of User object

Tags: java, setter

I was playing around with Hibernate and Postgres. 
I have a **User Class** as Below

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
public class UserDetails {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private int userId;
private String userName;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date joinedDate;
@Embedded
private Address homeAddress;
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="street", column = @Column(name="OFFICE_STREET_NAME")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="city", column = @Column(name="OFFICE_CITY_NAME")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="state", column = @Column(name="OFFICE_STATE_ABBR")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="pincode", column = @Column(name="OFFICE_PIN_CODE"))
})
private Address officeAddress;

@Lob
@Type(type="text")
private String description;

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public Date getJoinedDate() {
    return joinedDate;
}
public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) {
    this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public Address getHomeAddress() {
    return homeAddress;
}
public void setHomeAddress(Address homeAddress) {
    this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
}
public Address getOfficeAddress() {
    return officeAddress;
}
public void setOfficeAddress(Address officeAddress) {
    this.officeAddress = officeAddress;
}
}
```

and an **Address Class** as below

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {
@Column(name="STREET_NAME")
private String street;
@Column(name="CITY_NAME")
private String city;
@Column(name="STATE_NAME")
private String state;
@Column(name="PINCODE_NUMBER")
private String pincode;
public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getState() {
    return state;
}
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
public String getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}
public void setPincode(String pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}
}
```

The **main class** is as below

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.loganathan.divakar.dto.Address;
import org.loganathan.divakar.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserName("First User");
    user.setJoinedDate(new Date());
    user.setDescription("First User Description");

    Address addr = new Address();

    addr.setStreet("Home Street");
    addr.setCity("Home City");
    addr.setState("Home State Abbr");
    addr.setPincode("Home PinCode");
    user.setHomeAddress(addr);

    addr.setStreet("Office Street");
    addr.setCity("Office City");
    addr.setState("Office State");
    addr.setPincode("Office PinCode");
    user.setOfficeAddress(addr);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new 
    Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}

}
```

So now when I run the Main class, both the HomeAddress & OfficeAddress for the user object has the values(of OfficeAddress), I have intentionally used a same address object "addr".

```
Address addr = new Address();
```

First set the values to the addr object with home address details , and then set the addr object to the homeAddress field of UserDetails object(user)

```
addr.setStreet("Home Street");
addr.setCity("Home City");
addr.setState("Home State Abbr");
addr.setPincode("Home PinCode");
user.setHomeAddress(addr);
```

and then set the values to the addr object with Office address details , and then set the addr object to the officeAddress field of UserDetails object(user)

```
addr.setStreet("Office Street");
addr.setCity("Office City");
addr.setState("Office State");
addr.setPincode("Office PinCode");
user.setOfficeAddress(addr);
```

This works completely fine if I use two Address objects (homeAddr and offAddr objects in my MainClass to set the homeAddress and OfficeAddress values of the userDetails object.

But I wanted to try out using one Address object to set different values for Home and Office Address.

I know we can use the same address object to set values for the Home and Office Address fields of the UserDetails Class, logically. 
But I'm unable to understand, why the homeAddress values are being overridden with OfficeAddress values(even after setting the User.homeAddress field even before entering officeAddress values)

I even debugged using debug mode to see why the homeAddress values are being overridden with OfficeAddress values.

Any information to help understand why the home address value is overwritten by the Office address values is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Divakar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are still using the same address object. If you want them to be separate addresses, you will have to create a new address.

```
Address addr = new Address();
addr.setStreet("Home Street");
addr.setCity("Home City");
addr.setState("Home State Abbr");
addr.setPincode("Home PinCode");
user.setHomeAddress(addr);

addr = new Address(); // make a new address
addr.setStreet("Office Street");
addr.setCity("Office City");
addr.setState("Office State");
addr.setPincode("Office PinCode");
user.setOfficeAddress(addr);
```

When you set the address as the home address, `addr` and the user's `homeAddress` are referencing the same Address object, and changes to it will be reflected in both places.

Comment: Gotcha :) Thanks a lot, I got a bit tricked with the object reference part ;) Now things are clear.